# NavigationBar hidden in detailViewController when presented modally

Tags: iphone, uisplitviewcontroller

I am basically presenting my DetailViewController as modalView.In the modalView navigation bar is never visible, though I am not hiding it any where.Please help!

Comment: What navigation bar are you expecting to appear? Does the modal view have it's own nav bar?

Comment: Please let me know why this question is being downvoted.May be the reason help me in future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WriteReviewController *newReview = [[WriteReviewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WriteReviewController" bundle:nil];

UINavigationController *modalNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:newReview];

// This is intended to be presented in another view controller class
modalNavController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;  
[self.parentViewController presentModalViewController:modalNavController animated:YES]; 
[modalNavController release];
```

This code worked for me